# MSN homepage opens whenever my internet goes down

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, internet

When I get the link I'll edit it to be on here also not sure what SE site to post this on, thought this would be my best bet.

My internet has been really bad lately so it keeps going down, BT is sending someone over soon.

Every time my internet goes down, after about 1 minute a re-direct link (From BT by the looks of the link) opens my Chrome and directs me to the MSN homepage. Of course it does not load until my internet comes back on but it does not only open one. After about 5 minutes it has opened like 10 pages. All the exact same.

Anyone know how to stop this? It is getting annoying but I know it's not a virus as I have scanned my computer many times and checked through some major files for any anomalies, but nothing in the end.

- OS - Windows 8.1
- Internet provider - BT (not inifnity)
- Default browser - Google Chrome
- Home page - google.co.uk

Comment: Are you running any Chrome extentions?

Comment: BetterTTV, AdBlockPlus, Plug+ I had them all before this issue though.

Comment: Does this happen on other computers or devices?  Did your ISP have you install any special software?

Comment: @Steven Nope and nope.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable it via setting following registry entry from 1 to 0:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet\EnableActiveProbing

[From Microsoft answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_8/windows-8-goes-to-bing-by-itself-all-the-time/386e9a25-8149-4ee6-84b4-65332022c2a7)

Comment: Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).

Comment: Haha, this was probably the worst time to reply as Im now on holiday! As soon as I get back though I will try this thanks.

Comment: @ِDragonLord the description is sufficient in case of link goes down.