# What is launching Chrome with MSN at system startup?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, dell-latitude

Since [kb3000850](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3000850) installed itself on my Dell Win8 laptop, Chrome launches with MSN every time I boot my machine, no doubt to make sure all my tracking cookies are up to date. The chrome startup settings are clean. I've found and removed the dell.msn.com url from the default page setting in my system internet settings. I've installed and run [Autoruns](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjOsr6v6bPMAhXJL8AKHXnEBGcQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fsysinternals%2Fbb963902.aspx&usg=AFQjCNEYeGmDPrEeqe619y34pniru-K5oA&sig2=_Cv33h9-QuE3ztyHR12YdA), and can't see anything that points to chrome. Does anyone have tips for how to locate and stop this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSN homepage opens whenever my internet goes down](http://superuser.com/questions/938037/msn-homepage-opens-whenever-my-internet-goes-down)

Comment: Disable `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet\EnableActiveProbing` - set to `0`

Comment: Is Chrome your default browser? If so, any URL will open it. Try some of the other tools in the [SysInternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062): `procexp` will show you Chrome's parent process (if still running), and `procmon` will monitor registry and file accesses, with an option for boot logging.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Crossed with you yet again! Your suggestion seems a good one, though I checked on Win10 and I found that the registry entry you cite is set to `1`, but I don't get the problem. Maybe they changed the probing in the update from Win8.

Comment: Is MSN your homepage? Are there any entries in your Startup folder? Have you checked Task Scheduler for a task that might cause this? And finally, are you on a domain and/or do you have Group Policy on your machine?